# android keyboard background

Tags: keyboard, customization, sony-xperia

Can I change the background of my keyboard, such as using my own pictures as the background of the keyboard?

I searched this for a long time but there's still no way to do that. I've download an app called [GO Keyboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.jb.gokeyboard), it allows me to use my own pictures; but when I type I can't see the conversations above: the whole page is just my keyboard and a box to show what I am typing.

Can anybody tell me how to set the background of my keyboard with my own pictures? This means a lot to me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot where you can't see the conversations using GO Keyboard. I've changed wallpaper with GO Keyboard, and I have no issues. Also using GO SMS Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Choose your go keyboard app. Then themes. In the top right corner there is a icon that looks like a gallery its right about the word LOCAL. once you choose that it says customize theme.. you can from there choose your portrait or landscape background and customize it.. To choose your own photo you will need to have the photo saved in your gallery of pictures.